# How to make a random sample in Openrefine?

Tags: random, data-cleaning, openrefine

Very often we need to extract random samples of a large `dataset`? What is the best way to do it on `openrefine`? This might be useful for practitioners used to do it in `R` and `Python`.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Refine has not built-in function for that, but you can use Python/Jython to create a new column of random integers. eg, if you have 100 000 rows :

```
import random
return random.randint(0, 100000)
```

Then, you can sort this columns, reorder rows permanently and select for example the first thousand with a custom text facet :

```
row.index < 1000
```

EDIT : I forgot that [this extension](https://github.com/ostephens/refine-gokbutils) from @OwenStephens adds a randomNumber GREL function. Feel free to install it.

[image]

Comment: That helps a lot. Thanks once again! Ettore!

Comment: You're welcome. Answer edited by the way. Note: If you have specific questions about OpenRefine, you can also ask them on the dedicated [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openrefine).